# Ad Hoc profile issue

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have this error, is anyone know what is the problem?
I check and I have Entitlements key in both adHoc and main provisioning profile but I do not know why I have this error

```
 DTFetchSymbols[512] <Notice>:   
 /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld/dyld_shared_cache_armv7s
 DTFetchSymbols[512] <Notice>: kCommand_ListFilesPlist
 syslog_relay[377] <Notice>: syslog_relay found the ASL prompt. Starting...
 profiled[84] <Notice>: (Note ) MC: Provisioning profiles changed
 mobile_installation_proxy[375] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Please include the 
 kCFBundleIdentifierKey in the options dictionary when installing an app.
 mobile_installation_proxy[375] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app with unknown
  bundleID
 installd[384] <Notice>: 0x603000 -[MIClientConnection
 _doBackgroundInstallationForPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of 
 "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/Test.ipa" type Customer requested by  
 mobile_installation_proxy (pid 375)
 installd[384] <Notice>: 0x603000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: 
 Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=test.testTest.Test; Version=3, ShortVersion=3.1.2>
 misagent[378] <Error>: attempt to install invalid profile: 0xe8008012
 installd[384] <Error>: 0x603000 -[MIInstallableBundle 
 _installEmbeddedProfileInBundle:]: Could not install embedded profile: 0xe8008012 
 (Unsupported device)
 installd[384] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
 installd[384] <Error>: entitlement 'beta-reports-active' has value not permitted by 
 provisioning profile 'test TEST AdHoc 2015'
 installd[384] <Error>: 0x603000 -[MICodeSigningVerifier performValidationWithError:]:
 186: Failed to verify code signature of <MIExecutableBundle : path =  /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.asUxKy/extracted/Payload/Test.app identifier = test.Test.testTest type = 4> : 0xe8008016 (Entitlements found that are not permitted by provisioning profile)

 installd[384] <Error>: 0x603000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: 
 Verification stage failed
 mobile_installation_proxy[375] <Error>: 0x603000 
__MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices_block_invoke240: Returned error Error 
Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=13 "Failed to verify code signature of 
<MIExecutableBundle : path =     /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.asUxKy/extracted/Payload/Test.app identifier = test.Test.testTest type = 4> : 0xe8008016 (Entitlements found that are not permitted by provisioning profile)" UserInfo=0x17566950 {LibMISErrorNumber=-402620394, LegacyErrorString=ApplicationVerificationFailed, FunctionName=-[MICodeSigningVerifier performValidationWithError:], NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to verify code signature of <MIExecutableBundle : path = 
       /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.asUxKy/extracted/ Payload/Test.app identifier = test.Test.testTest type = 4> : 0xe8008016 (Entitlements found   that are not permitted by provisioning profile), SourceFileLine=186}
 mobile_installation_proxy[375] <Warning>: ERROR:    MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil
 mobile_installation_proxy[375] <Error>: 0x581000 handle_install: Installation failed:   Error Domain=LaunchServicesError Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)" UserInfo=0x17566a30 {Error=ApplicationVerificationFailed, ErrorDetail=-402620394, ErrorDescription=Failed to verify code signature of <MIExecutableBundle : path = /private/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.asUxKy/extracted/Payload/Test.app identifier = test.Test.testTest type = 4> : 0xe8008016 (Entitlements found that are not permitted by provisioning profile)}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I saw this this morning.  very odd.  I had to regenerate the provisioning file and then it worked fine.

Comment: @MikeM what it related to Apple or itunes bug or apple provisioning site problem?

Comment: I don't know what caused it - I just regenerated the provisioning file, refreshed Xcode to use the new provisioning, and then it worked.

Comment: same thing happens on my iPhone 6 with iOS 8. seems to be device specific. but deleting/refreshing my local provisioning profiles didn't help so far.

Answer (score 1):

For me beta-reports-active was the issue: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1830/_index.html

I have two Xcode archives that I can export for ad-hoc distribution. AFAIK they are based on the same code and created the same way (Xcode>Product>Archive). During the export wizard one archive shows me "beta-reports-active" under entitlements the other doesn't. I get the same error message as the OP when trying to install the ipas with the "beta-reports-active" entitlement.
I did recreate the provisioning profile and reinstalled the appstore distribution profile as well before archiving again which produced the archive without the "beta-reports-active" entitlement, but i'm not sure if that was the cause.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this started to happen since Xcode 7.

I used to make AdHoc .ipa for over-the-air distribution via

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath "/path/to/My App 9-24-15, 21.21.xcarchive" -exportPath /path/to/MyApp_AdHoc.ipa -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile "MyApp Ad Hoc Distribution Profile"
```

(the `.xcarchive` made by Xcode)

Steps, how I fixed this:

1. No longer using `xcodebuild`, but instead let Xcode do the .ipa for me via "Export..." command in the Organizer
2. [Set up Xcode to automatically manage my provisioning profiles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1814/_index.html)
3. From the doc above I made one exception: in target's **Build Settings** under **Code Signing Identify** I do specify *iOS Developer* for Debug builds and *iOS Distribution* for Release builds
4. Close Xcode
5. Refresh an *App Store Provision Profile* as described in [The beta-reports-active Entitlement Technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1830/_index.html), BUT before downloading the Provision Profile via Xcode (Step 9) I have removed it from here

   ```
   ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles
   ```
6. Remove DerivedData folder

   ```
   rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
   ```
7. Remove Xcode Cache (just in case)

   ```
   sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
   ```
8. Launch Xcode again
9. Download the *App Store Provision Profile* via **Preferences...** -> **Accounts**
10. Achieve
11. Make sure when I "Export..." via Xcode there is NO `beta-reports-active` key under app's Entitlements (if you have one - that won't work for AdHoc builds)

Answer (score 1):

This started happening after upgrading from XCode 6 to 8, and what resolved the problem was adding the following:

-exportProvisioningProfile "MyApp Ad Hoc Distribution Profile"

to my xcodebuild -exportArchive command line.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you, but what I did that solved it was I deleted my provisioning profile for the app.  I then recreated it in the developer portal.  Next I took the build I had just made and had XCode export it (Organizer > Export > Save for Ad Hoc Deployment), verified it was using the provisioning profile I just made and then uploaded that to testflight and I was able to install it on my phone.  I am using an iPhone 6 running ios 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur if you build and sign your IPA from command line (CI System like Jenkins) and need to embed a mobile provisioning profile to use Apple Push Notifications:

`xcrun [...] --sign "<<CERTIFICATE NAME>>" --embed "<</path/to/mobileprovision>>"`

In that case the mobile provisioning profile you are trying to embed is not the same you use in xcode.

---

The code example you provided also shows the `'beta-reports-active'` entitlement that indicates you are using a beta version. If you look here on StackOverflow you will find a lot of posts with solutions about that particular issue.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more in that?

Comment: Still have this issue, and this is the exact same case: embedding a profile for APNS. I use `shenzhen` with my provisioning profile and my signing identity.

Comment: `beta-reports-active` doesn't indicate you're using a beta; it indicates that you can distribute your build using Apple's TestFlight if you want.